# Convert IPv6 to long without external library

Tags: python, python-2.x, ipv6

wondering if its possible to convert IPv6 to long integer using Python version 2.6.6 without any external library?

I dont have the luxury to install any external library on this instance due to certain reason :(

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and upgrade to Python 3, where you'll have [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) available to you

Comment: I wish I can do that. I've tried it though in my local (and it was super easy). LOL. But I have this one specific instance that I cant simply upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, check out the implementation for the classmethod [`_BaseV6._ip_int_from_string()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/229335ceef32e561cf6b5070f1b1175785702719/Lib/ipaddress.py#L1552), from the `ipaddress` module, though the module itself was added in Python 3.3.

When you call `ipaddress.IPv6Address('2001:db8::')` (passing a Python3 `str`), [this is what gets called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/229335ceef32e561cf6b5070f1b1175785702719/Lib/ipaddress.py#L1832).

That parsing function accounts for a number of odds-and-ends cases, such as an IPv4-style suffix.  *If* your function was constrained to a number of rules that are a subset of an "allowable Ipv6 string," you could probably simplify that method.  But suffice it to say that there's a reason that the implementation is a couple hundred lines of fairly dense code.